# TS Backend Dev: `prisma generate` cannot find installed `@tsed/prisma` package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, prisma, koa

I am trying to marry Ts.Ed v7.35 and prisma v5.2 following [this official tutorial](https://tsed.io/tutorials/prisma-client.html).

After running `npm install` I get this error while executing `npx prisma generate`:

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Error: Generator "@tsed/prisma" failed:

/bin/sh: 1: @tsed/prisma: not found
```

Those are the files inside *./node_modules/@tsed/prisma/*:

```bash
$> ls -lah ./node_modules/@tsed/prisma/
drwxrwxr-x  5 dev dev 4.0K Sep 11 20:35 lib/
drwxrwxr-x  3 dev dev 4.0K Sep 11 20:35 node_modules/
drwxrwxr-x  2 dev dev 4.0K Sep 11 20:35 scripts/
-rw-rw-r--  1 dev dev  135 Sep 11 20:35 .eslintignore
-rw-rw-r--  1 dev dev   50 Sep 11 20:35 .eslintrc.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 dev dev 2.1K Sep 11 20:35 package.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 dev dev 9.6K Sep 11 20:35 readme.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 dev dev  754 Sep 11 20:35 tsconfig.esm.json
```

Thusly, the package is obviously installed. I hope somebody might see what I am missing...
Great htanks to you all. <3

---

**Project structure:**

```bash
drwxrwxr-x 335 dev dev  12K Sep 11 21:19 node_modules/
drwxrwxr-x   3 dev dev 4.0K Sep 11 21:18 prisma/
drwxrwxr-x   4 dev dev 4.0K Sep 11 19:18 src/
-rw-rw-r--   1 dev dev   46 Sep 11 14:14 .env
-rw-rw-r--   1 dev dev 189K Sep 11 21:19 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 dev dev 1.4K Sep 11 21:17 package.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 dev dev    0 Sep  8 13:32 readme.md
-rw-rw-r--   1 dev dev  776 Sep 11 20:34 tsconfig.json
```

**package.json:**

```json
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "db:init": "npx prisma generate",
    "db:migrate": "npx prisma migrate dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^8.12.0",
    "koa": "^2.14.2",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.4.1",
    "koa-compress": "^5.1.1",
    "koa-override": "^3.0.0",
    "@koa/cors": "^4.0.0",
    "@koa/router": "^12.0.0",
    "prisma": "^5.2.0",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.2.0",
    "@tsed/ajv": "^7.35.0",
    "@tsed/common": "^7.35.0",
    "@tsed/core": "^7.35.0",
    "@tsed/di": "^7.35.0",
    "@tsed/json-mapper": "^7.35.0",
    "@tsed/platform-koa": "^7.35.0",
    "@tsed/prisma": "^7.35.0",
    "@tsed/schema": "^7.35.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/koa": "^2.13.8",
    "@types/koa__cors": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/koa__router": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.10",
    "@types/koa-compress": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/koa-override": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^20.5.9",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

**prisma/schema.prisma:**

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

generator tsed {
  provider = "@tsed/prisma"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Demo {
  /// @TsEd.Groups("!creation")
  id    Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  uuid  String  @unique
  data  String
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "es7",
      "dom",
      "ESNext.AsyncIterable"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/",
    "dist/",
    "public/",
    "test/"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've forgot to install the @tsed/prisma package.

The first step of the tutorial is pretty clear ;)

```
npm i -D prisma
npm i @tsed/prisma @prisma/client
```

Also the prisma schema seems to be wrong if we compare it to the given example:

```
generator tsed {
  provider = "tsed-prisma"
}
```

Please follow the guideline ;)

Also, Ts.ED provide a CLI to generate a fresh project with Prisma feature. Don't hesitate to use it.

See you
Romain

Comment: In *package.json* is included: "@tsed/prisma": "^7.35.0" and "@prisma/client": "^5.2.0".

Inside *node_modules/* both packages can be found.

Comment: With the suggested provider it did work (plus adding ts-node as dependecy). I used multiple sources. In that case, the schema came straight from the readme on [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tsed/prisma). There seems to be an inconsistency between the tutorial on [tsed.io](https://tsed.io/tutorials/prisma-client.html) and the [repository](https://github.com/tsedio/tsed/tree/production/packages/orm/prisma).

Thank you a lot for the quick help.